# Expected JsonObject but was JsonPrimitive

Tags: android, json, retrofit

I am using *retrofit* to parse JSON. I'm getting an exception while parsing a JSON response. My response is dynamic means that when I'm getting a successful response the response key is successful, but when I'm getting a fail response it turns to an error. How can I parse that response?

When I'm getting a fail response it's giving me a proper result, but when I'm getting a successful response it's going to end in failure and gives me an exception that `Expected JsonObject but was JsonPrimitive`.

Comment: Please explore your question by adding code & error response

Comment: For me, the response was a long HTML response because of an error, which is not a Jasonable data.

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar problem where server returned sometimes a JsonObject and sometimes a JsonPrimitive. When JsonPrimitive was returned I got 200 OK but it still ends up in onFailure because the types differed ( **It expected a JsonObject but found a JsonPrimitive** ).

```
public final class JsonPrimitive extends JsonElement

public final class JsonObject extends JsonElement
```

The com.google.gson documentation states that booth JsonPrimitive and JsonObject extend JsonElement so why not do:

```
JsonObject jsonObject = createJsonObject();
Call<JsonElement> requestCall = SomeInterface.sendRequest(jsonObject);
requestCall.enqueue(new Callback<JsonElement>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<JsonElement> call, Response<JsonElement> response) {
        //Now when you get a JsonPrimitive it will still end up here because 
        //JsonPrimitive extends JsonElement
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<JsonElement> call, Throwable t) {
    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Jsonobject and jsonprimitive is different type each other .

> JsonObject { "name":"John", "age":30, "car":null }
>
> JsonPrimitive (string, number, boolean)

Your response model is wrong . try this .

http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Answer (score 0):

Your API response is String and you try to get JsonObject.
check your API in [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/downloads/) and sure API response is JsonObject.